# 'pydoc -w EXPRESSIONS' does not work but 'pydoc EXPRESSIONS' does. Why? (all capitalized help topics)

Tags: python, pydoc

`pydoc EXPRESSIONS` work perfectly fine but `pydoc -w EXPRESSIONS` does not. Why is that? (the 
 `w` option write the output to a html file)
The same is true for other capitalized help topics such as FORMATTING or TUPLELITERALS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/pydoc.py) you can see that [when using the switch '-w'](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/pydoc.py#l2311) pydoc uses the function writedoc, [otherwise](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/pydoc.py#l2325) to the class Helper. In the Helper-class EXPRESSIONS is defined under line [1666](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/pydoc.py#l1666) . The function writedoc does not utilize this nor does it use the Helper class.

Same for [FORMATTING](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/pydoc.py#l1644) and [TUPLELITERALS](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/pydoc.py#l1700)

Might qualify for a bug report, in my opinion.