# Markup language of output from python's help function?

Tags: python

does the output of `help(something)` follow some markup language that is easy to format in html? I know about `pydoc -w [topic]` but  there are two problems:

- customization of the style is not easy (http://bugs.python.org/issue10716) and
- `pydoc -w` fails for some topics (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10333615/1318686)

Below is some example output generated by `help('def')`. It has some typical characteristics of other markup languages. E.g. spaces for code blocks, ` for inline code, ** to highlight...

Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
Function definitions
********************

A function definition

Multiple decorators are applied in
nested fashion. For example, the following code:

   @f1(arg)
   @f2
   def func(): pass

just like a function defined by a lambda form.  The "``def``" form is
actually more powerful since it allows the execution of multiple
statements.

**Programmer's note:** Functions are first-class
```

Answer (score 1):

Most people use [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) and use [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) to convert it to HTML and other formats.

There are no requirements on how to format the docstring of a function though.

Comment: great, thanks! Can I use these tools to replace `pydoc -w [topic]`? I basically want to generate help files on the fly in html without necessarily being online...